# How can I install nltk for Python 3?

Tags: software-installation, python3

I have installed nltk on my Ubuntu 16.0.4.

Natural language tool kit is working on Python 2.7 but not on Python 3.

How can I install it for Python 3?

Comment: Please describe the expected and current outcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python 2 and 3 live in different worlds, they have their own environments and packages. In this case, if you just need a globally installed package available from the system Python 3 environment, you can use apt to install `python3-nltk`:

```
sudo apt install python3-nltk
```

Developing things against the system Python environment is a little risky though. As You update to newer releases of Ubuntu, these packages will update too. That can cause breakages. It can also mean you're held back on an older package of something.

For more localised development, I'd really consider looking into Virtualenv, pipenv, or one of the multitude of other separating techniques Python has at its disposal.

---

The [official installation instructions](http://www.nltk.org/install.html) would have you install the package with pip (or pip3) into the system environment. This will likely work but could have serious ramifications on the system you're doing it to. Ubuntu itself needs a Python environment so it's best not to mess around with it outside the things that a properly packaged.

Additionally, it passes the `-U` flag which will upgrade the package and anything it depends on to the latest PyPI-available version. Great for getting the latest and greatest, but what happens when you inadvertantly upgrade somehthing Ubuntu requires to an incompatible version?

If you read `sudo pip install ...` in documentation, the author might not understand the finer points of system package management. Seriously, it can trash an Ubuntu install.

Answer (score 2):

For Python 3, from the command line (specifically, from your shell), use:

```
sudo pip3 install nltk
```

Or, when you are in the spyder IPython console instead your shell, you can use:

```
!pip3 install nltk
```

The leading `!` character causes a shell command to be run.

Comment: I didn't change this in my edit since perhaps you intend it, but you may want to **[edit]** this to clarify why you recommend `sudo` in one case but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, for safer installation inside virtualenv:

1. Install NLTK:

   ```
   sudo pip install -U nltk
   ```
2. Install Numpy (optional):

   ```
   sudo pip install -U numpy
   ```
3. Test installation:

   ```
   python then type import nltk
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you facing problem to install nltk on python3.. Simply follow these steps :

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Type <kbd>Y</kbd> and update all dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Type <kbd>Y</kbd> to remove unnecessary files.

```
sudo apt-get autoclean 
pip3 install nltk
python3
>import nltk
nltk.download('all-nltk')e
```